# HTML input file capture=camera for multiple files

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I'm trying to make a mobile web application (both for IOS and Android) that lets the user upload some pictures, either by choosing them from the library or by taking them with the device camera.

I'm using this input `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" multiple>`. It works great, it opens the camera and it lets me choose to use the photo or to try again, but the multiple attribute doesn't work. I can only take one photo per time.

Am i missing something? Maybe the multiple attribute is not supported?

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 1):

I think it actually is impossible to take multiple pictures with the camera this way before uploading, and that it's only possible to upload multiples with the file browser.

You will need to use JavaScript and the MediaStream functionality, pretty much writing a quick camera app yourself. It works but there are a few pitfalls with how manufacturers report sensors etc.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove,

```
capture="camera"
```

then it will open on gallery directly and allow multiple selection.

Comment: The OP wanted the user to be able to take multiple photos for one input, not to open the gallery.